# Wood to brick corner leak

Tags: walls, leak

Started renting a place and discovered that the basement leaks every time it rains.  Looks like its coming from this corner where the brick meets the wood wall.  Unfortunately, the leasing office won't fix it so I'm not looking for a full fix, just  a patch. Doesn't look like there is a simple fix but just anything I can do to stop water from coming in for the short while I'll be renting this place. Any idea what I can do here? [image]

Comment: There is no simple fix.  The best you could do is station a dehumidifier and/or fan at the site to ameliorate the problem.  How much water comes through?

Answer (score 2):

Contact your landlord. Most tenants are not permitted to do any work to rented units, you could be liable for damages if work you perform isn't done correctly.

Secondly, it is your landlords responsibility to take care of these types of issues. I would fight them on this.

Comment: And notify the local authorities (health dept?) because it could turn into a moldy health hazard.